# Divide group sum by total sum

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, summarize

I am using the dplyr package. Let's suppose I have the below table.

| Group | count |
| --- | --- |
| A | 20 |
| A | 10 |
| B | 30 |
| B | 35 |
| C | 50 |
| C | 60 |

My goal is to create a summary table that contains the mean per each group, and also, the percentage of the mean of each group compared to the total means added together. So the final table will look like this:

| Group | avg | prcnt_of_total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 15 | .14 |
| B | 32.5 | .31 |
| C | 55 | .53 |

For example, 0.14 is the result of the following calculation: 15/(15+32.5+55)

Right now, I was only able to produce the first column code that calculates the mean for each group:

```
summary_df<- df %>% 
             group_by(Group)%>% 
             summarise(avg=mean(count))
```

I still don't know how to produce the prcnt_of_total column. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```r
df <- read.table(text="Group    count
A   20
A   10
B   30
B   35
C   50
C   60", header = TRUE)

library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(Group) %>%
  summarise(avg = mean(count)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(prcnt_of_total = prop.table(avg))
#> # A tibble: 3 × 3
#>   Group   avg prcnt_of_total
#>   <chr> <dbl>          <dbl>
#> 1 A      15            0.146
#> 2 B      32.5          0.317
#> 3 C      55            0.537
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: That solves it without going out of the sequence. Thanks!

Comment: Or `mutate(prcnt_of_total = avg/sum(avg))`, even if I like the use of `prop.table`

Comment: Upvote but from the documentation: *"Note: `prop.table` is an earlier name, retained for back-compatibility."* The newer name for this function is `proportions`.

Answer (score 1):

We can drop the group in `summarise` itself.

```r
library(dplyr)

df1 %>% 
  group_by(Group) %>% 
  summarise(avg = mean(count), .groups = "drop") %>% 
  mutate(prcnt_of_total = avg/sum(avg))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>   Group   avg prcnt_of_total
#>   <chr> <dbl>          <dbl>
#> 1 A      15            0.146
#> 2 B      32.5          0.317
#> 3 C      55            0.537
```

On another note, I am not sure if getting the average divided by the sum of averages is a meaningful metric unless we are sure to have the same number of entries per group. Given that, I suggested another solution as well.

```
## if you always have the same number of rows between the groups
df1 %>% 
  group_by(Group) %>% 
  summarise(avg = mean(count),
            prcnt_of_total = sum(count)/sum(.$count)) 
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>   Group   avg prcnt_of_total
#>   <chr> <dbl>          <dbl>
#> 1 A      15            0.146
#> 2 B      32.5          0.317
#> 3 C      55            0.537
```

##### Data:

```
read.table(text =  "Group count
                    A     20
                    A     10
                    B     30
                    B     35
                    C     50
                    C     60", 
           header = T, stringsAsFactors = F) -> df1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(Group) %>%
  summarize(avg = mean(count), prcent_of_total = sum(count)/sum(df$count))
```

Output:

```
  Group   avg prcent_of_total
  <chr> <dbl>           <dbl>
1 A      15             0.146
2 B      32.5           0.317
3 C      55             0.537
```

`data.table` is similar:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)[,.(avg = mean(count), prcent_of_total = sum(count)/sum(df$count)),Group]
```

Comment: Does dplyr automatically apply functions on the whole column if we put data.frame$column? doesn't take into consideration any current grouping?

Comment: Note that my approach is the same as @M-- second solution,. and yes, by referrring to `df` the denominator calculation will be done over the entire frame (not by group)